# What is the optimal weight within the BMI range?

Tags: weight

[BMI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Body_mass_index) is a commonly used measure to determine whether or not a person is at a healthy weight. A person is said to be overweight if they are above 25 and underweight if below 18.5. [This question](https://health.stackexchange.com/q/3176/3258) asks what the scientific basis is for BMI ranges, but does not question the difference between the values within that range.

Between the upper and lower "healthy" limits is a rather large range of weights. Anecdotally, when I am at a BMI of 25 I still look and feel rather overweight (flabby, bulging belly, etc.). I've only ever been as low as around 21 or 22 BMI, at which point I am rather slim, and at the weight I'd need to be to achieve 18.5 I imagine I would be very skinny, too slender by my personal standards.

Is it really the case that someone at a BMI of 18.5 would be equally as healthy as someone at 21.75 (the midpoint) or 25? By healthy I mean equivalent risk of long term illnesses, early death, etc. (assuming other health-related factors to be the same).

If not, then is there a more accurate way to determine an optimally healthy weight (as opposed to merely a range of healthy weights)? Having been unable to find any information on this point, my target weight is a BMI of 21.75, but I would like to fine tune this if possible.

Comment: Look up body fat percentage. BMI is a universal number -- universally useless, misleading and stupid.

Comment: @CareyGregory there are certainly issues with it, but it is far from useless. It provides a simple and accessible way to track and set goals for weight and when used as a statistical measure, we can use it to identify correlations to health.

Comment: Sure, assuming the person isn't physically fit and muscular, in which case the number is extremely misleading. A measure with such a huge limitation that has no way of expressing that limitation is so flawed as to be useless.

Comment: @CareyGregory You're looking at it from the point of view of an individual (and of course every individual is different). I am talking about statistics. When you look at a sufficiently large sample size, then you can make generalised correlations. In the same way that you can say "males are more likely to have a car accident than females" and that information is useful for calculating insurance premiums, but that doesn't mean it applies to a specific male who happens to be a very skilled and careful driver.

Comment: Your second question was if there's a more accurate way to determine optimal weight. I would say yes, and it's not BMI. Body fat % works for all body types across all populations. BMI does not.

Comment: [Let your own body determine what weight it should be at for optimal health by gradually starting to exercise a lot harder and eating more healthy foods](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/a/29893/8763).

Answer (score 4):

BMI is calculated from [this formula](https://www.cdc.gov/healthyweight/assessing/bmi/adult_bmi/index.html), only looking at the height and weight of a person.

However, [muscle is bulkier than fat](http://www.everydayhealth.com/weight/busting-the-muscle-weighs-more-than-fat-myth.aspx), so two people could have the same BMI but be at different health levels (for example, if people A and B are the same height and weight then they will have the same BMI. However, person A could be mostly muscle and in good shape they will be healthier than person B who has less muscle weight and more fat weight and isn't in as good of shape).

As stated in the comments above, Body Fat % is a better way to determine health.